# Install kubuntu inside window 8 using wbui

Tags: windows-8, kubuntu

I am getting error to install kubuntu 12.04 inside window 8 using wubi installer. I want to know is this is possible or i have to wait until next relies of kubuntu.

Comment: At least specify what error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> Wubi does not work on any new PC with the Windows 8 logo or using UEFI firmware. Please use a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu, installed directly to its own partition instead. For more information see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

If you have one of the newer PCs, it will not work.